# Unable to evaluate integral in DSolve solution

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I define the PDE

```
PDE1 = \[Rho] G[q, w] - (\[Rho] w + S - q) D[G[q, w], {w, 1}] - \[Mu] q D[G[q, w], {q, 1}]
```

which Mathematica is able to solve in terms of an arbitrary function `C[1]` and an integral:

```
SOLN1 = DSolve[
   {
    PDE1 == Log[w]
    },
   G,
   {q, w}
   ] // FullSimplify


(*
{{G -> Function[{q, w}, 
    q^(\[Rho]/\[Mu]) (C[1][(
        q^(-(\[Rho]/\[Mu])) (S \[Mu] + q \[Rho] - S \[Rho] + 
           w \[Mu] \[Rho] - w \[Rho]^2))/((\[Mu] - \[Rho]) \[Rho])] + 
       Inactive[Integrate][-((
         K[1]^(-1 - \[Rho]/\[Mu])
           Log[(-S \[Mu] + S \[Rho] - \[Rho] K[1] + (
            q^(-(\[Rho]/\[Mu])) \[Mu] (S \[Mu] + q \[Rho] - S \[Rho] +
                w \[Mu] \[Rho] - w \[Rho]^2) K[
              1]^(\[Rho]/\[Mu]))/(\[Mu] - \[Rho]) - (
            q^(-(\[Rho]/\[Mu])) \[Rho] (S \[Mu] + q \[Rho] - 
               S \[Rho] + w \[Mu] \[Rho] - w \[Rho]^2) K[
              1]^(\[Rho]/\[Mu]))/(\[Mu] - \[Rho]))/((\[Mu] - \[Rho]) \
\[Rho])])/\[Mu]), {K[1], 1, q}])]}}
*)
```

Notice that the limits of this integral are $(1, q)$, where $q$ is one of the arguments of the function $G$. If I try to evaluate this function for some constants a particular choice for `C[1]`, the integral does not evaluate:

```
CONS = {\[Rho] -> 0.04, S -> 5, \[Mu] -> 0.07}

G[10, 100] /. SOLN1 /. C[1][x_] -> Log[x] /. CONS // Activate

(*
{3.72759 (5.00919 + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(10\)]\(\(-
\*FractionBox[\(14.285714285714285`\ Log[
          833.3333333333333`\ \((\(-0.15000000000000002`\) + 
             0.17974061828374174`\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(K[1]\), \(0.5714285714285714`\)] - 
             0.04`\ K[1])\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(K[
          1]\), \(1.5714285714285714`\)]]\) \[DifferentialD]K[1]\)\))}
*)
```

Where am I going wrong? I would like to be able to evaluate the function, look at 3D plots etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rationalize it first, then it works (just do not ask me why :)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
DE1 = ρ G[q, w] - (ρ w + S - q) D[G[q, w], {w, 1}] - μ q D[G[q, w], {q, 1}];
SOLN1 = DSolve[{PDE1 == Log[w]}, G, {q, w}] // FullSimplify;
CONS = {ρ -> 0.04, S -> 5, μ -> 0.07};
G[10, 100] /. SOLN1 /. C[1][x_] -> Log[x] /. CONS // Rationalize;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Activate[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]